# Firefox is changing file extensions on downloads

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, download, file-association, file-extension

Today I downloaded a .reg file, and Firefox made it a .reg.txt file.  I downloaded a .zip file and Firefox made it a .zip.htm file.  Both files worked fine when I fixed the extensions.  What happened to Firefox? I haven't had this problem before.

Firefox 3.6.6, Windows XP Home SP3 w/all updates.

Comment: What content type (MIME) is the server responding? You could examine it with an addon like *Live HTTP Headers* from https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/3829/.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would install [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org),

However, if the Windows built in zip component is not working, you can try re-initilising it by going to the command prompt and typing the following commands:

> `regsvr32 zipfldr.dll`
>
> `cmd /c assoc .zip=CompressedFolder`

Comment: I fixed the zip file by renaming it, and updated the problem description to address the real issue.

Comment: Any idea why Firefox is now changing all the extensions on it's downloads?

Comment: @robert55 no, I have never seen this. What site are you doing the downloads from and is it only this site or is it any site?

Comment: Different sites.  It's still doing it, with all file types except exe's.  It's adding .txt, .htm, or .aspx to everything else.

Comment: @Wil: you're not really answering Robert's question. The .reg.txt example indicates that this is a Firefox problem, at least has nothing to do with ZIP.

Comment: @stevenvh - The question was changed after I wrote the answer.